# Where should I create a file so that any process can access it?

Tags: files, filesystems, users

I'm making a program that can be created multiple times by multiple users and I was thinking that It will be nice to have a file where I keep track of the programs information ID, PID, port, etc... so that all the programs know what other instances of the program are running.

I want my program to work on multiple unix distributions (and also macOS) and I was wondering what is the best place to create the file, like `/var/{name}` or `/Library/{name}`, I might have to use a different path depending on the OS but the less different options I have the better.

Also my other alternative was making a server that runs in root and keeps track of that but I was thinking that it was too much for only keeping track of the running instances and that a file was a better option but what do you think?

Comment: If you don't run a server under its own id, any user can fake that info, confusing and possibly exploiting the instances run by the other users. I suggest that --if started by and run as a regular user-- your program should IGNORE any other instance run by other users. Anything else is hard to impossible to get right.

Comment: I wonder if /run is used outside of Linux?

Comment: it _"would be nice"_? In most cases, it's probably not considered nice for a program to store data around that isn't related to what it actually has a _need_ to do. What does that program do, and why do copies of it need to know where the others are running?

Comment: @user414777 I was thinking about the security too, but for that to be a problem the attacker needs to log in to any user and if that happens you are already compromised.

Comment: @ilkkachu For context I need that info to do things similar to tmux, I want that file to contain the info of the running "instances/bashsessions", a list.

Comment: @user414777 For the security I'm thinking that maybe have a shared folder where the process can create their own file that anyone can read but only them can write. In that way I'm secure form an attacker changing other programs info but it can still create malicious files.

Comment: "the attacker needs to log in to any user and if that happens you are already compromised" that's a determination that only the sysadmin and the user should make. But anyways, you could make your program setgid and have it write to a directory/file owned by the group -- the same way games do to keep highest scores and some terminal emulators do to update the utmp/wtmp login databases. But people (quite rightfully) don't like installing and running setgid executables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to read [man 7 hier](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html) and `/var/run` seems to be what you are looking for. Because it is not so easy to get these information together by reading man pages and in case you have not been using that before: You can access process data via the procfs file system and under `/proc/$pid/env` you can access the environment variables set for your program. Taking advantage of that you could differentiate between different instances.

However note, that you need the correct access permissions to write into `/var/run` and that is usually archived by installing programs properly and preferably by your package manager. If you need a simpler solution, which also works for user accounts (!=root) there is another practice I am aware of: For example the X-server writes shared files to `/tmp` instead. That may be an alternative for you as well. `/tmp` or `/dev/shm` are usually further places, where volatile memory can be used. That is good practise for such "state" files, because it caueses less blocking, e.g. a hard disk could spin up from sleep or a memory card has only so many write cycles before it breaks.

How portable that is? I think `/dev/shm` is not the best choice on FreeBSD systems, the others should work and I am completely unaware on how it is under MacOS. I am confident though, that also Apple provides the hier(7) manual.

Comment: Thanks, the information I was looking for, the man page is clear as water the problem is how did you knew `man hier` had that info to begin with? I'm asking because I want to know how to answer my own question using man.

Comment: I am using linux for about 20 years now and I often find the `SEE ALSO` section of manuals very interesting. Note how hier(7) has a link to [file-hierarchy](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/file-hierarchy.7.html) for example. Interesting, right? Some time ago I think it must have been under Fedora, where `man 7 intro` had so many references to basic things, that I found hier(7). But that seems to have changed for some time now.